# Erro ao executar script

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Galera, estou tentando executar a query abaixo, porém, ocorre o seguinte erro.

"A conversão de um tipo de dados varchar em um tipo de dados datetime resultou em um valor fora do intervalo.".

```
select
    MesID,Mes,Ano,
 convert(time,dateadd(second,SUM ( DATEPART(hh,(convert(datetime,horas_uteis,1))) * 3600 +
 DATEPART(mi, (convert(datetime,horas_uteis,1))) * 60 + DATEPART(ss,(convert(datetime,horas_uteis,1)))),0),108)
 as horas
from (
    select
        dbo.FN_CALC_HORAS_UTEIS(s.SolDataFechamento,min(l.LogData)) as horas_uteis,
        datepart(month,s.SolDataFechamento) MesID,
        datename(month,s.SolDataFechamento) Mes,
        datepart(year,s.SolDataFechamento) Ano
    from Solicitacao S
        left join usuario U on (U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel) 
        left join Status ST on S.SolStatus = ST.CodStatus
        left join Log L on L.LogSolID = s.SolID 
    where
        S.proid in (2)
        and S.UsuIDResponsavel in (select UsuID from usuario where UsuIDGrupo = 1151 and EmpLiberada = 1 and UsuTipo = 'A'
and UsuID not in(84869,90093,95613,2359,596))
        and s.SolStatus = 9
        and l.LOGDESCRICAO like '%1057%' and convert(date,s.SolDataFechamento,103) between '01-01-2018' and '31-01-2018'
        group by s.SolDataFechamento
        having dbo.FN_CALC_HORAS_UTEIS(s.SolDataFechamento,min(l.LogData)) < '100:00'
) as X
group by MesID, Mes, Ano
```

Comment: qual o tipo de retorno de `FN_CALC_HORAS_UTEIS` ? aparentemente está tentando converter `100:00` para datetime, o que não será possível. Até porque em um timestamp, 100 horas seriam algo em torno de  4 dias e 3 horas

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, o 100 nesse caso não interfere, pois tirando ele, tbm ocorre o mesmo erro. O retorno de FN_CALC_HORAS_UTEIS são as horas uteis entre duas datas.

Comment: Qual base de dados está usando ? O 100, foi apenas uma sugestão, ok. Tipo de retorno da função pode ser timestamp, numeric, etc...

Comment: entendi. Estou usando o sql server 2012

Comment: dê um exemplo dos dados que são retornados na função, e que são colocados na coluna `horas_uteis`

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente você tentou fazer uma conversão de `varchar` para `date` em que resultou em uma data inválida, como por exmplo `30-02-2018`.

Verifique os predicados e as conversões realizadas no cabeçalho do seu `SQL` que envolvam datas na operação e se alguma delas estão inválidas.

Comment: repare que eu setei uma data que refere-se ao mes de janeiro e não tem saída do 30-02-2018;

Comment: Repare que eu não disse que você informou 30-02-2018, usei apenas tal data como exemplo de um período inválido.